# Is it safe to turn off apport reporting in xdiagnose?

Tags: xorg, apport

Since about one month, I experience multiple `System program problem detected` when I start a session in Ubuntu.  I didn't notice any further problems so I could work with the system without any trouble.

At first, I reported the problem, which means I had to type 12 types my password (one time for each 'crash').  Sometimes I did not have time or courage to do it.  I thought this would be solved with the next upgrade of Ubuntu (I am running Ubuntu 14.04) but so far, nothing happened.

So I tried to fix it and discovered a package called `xdiagnose` already installed on my system. I tried various options there, without success until I disabled `apport`. Since then, those messages do not show up anymore.  This is much more comfortable so far but are there any drawbacks? How can I know when to resume 'normal operations'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes I did not have time or courage to do it

Once is enough. All the other reports will error out with a message that this case is already registered (that is if it is the same error).

> I thought this would be solved with the next upgrade of Ubuntu

Often that is the case. But bugs also can be marked as invalid, or as won't fix, or as unclear.

> How can I know when to resume 'normal operations'?

Those reports end up on the bug pages on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) so track down the bug and see if there is any progress on it. For a more detailed answer you probably need to include an error report into the question (that will probably tell you the package against it is filed and the bug id you need).

> Is it safe to turn off apport reporting in xdiagnose?

Yes, it is safe! However, even if it was No: I see no reason for you to keep getting crash notices to report **;)**

Comment: Thank you.  Could you be more specific on how i search the Launchpad database.  I guess `system program problem detected` is too broad.  On the other hand,  the sent report is very large.  Would it contain some kind of id?

Comment: yes it should contain an ID. (the bug report ID to be specific). Find it and use the link in the answer to search for it ;)

Comment: Waouw, good link.  Other questions: if i understand you well, the second and subsequent times I sent a report, I should have had some kind of message saying the case was already registered (which i did not see)? Last one: can I find back reports sent earlier?